# Looping in an array to attain nearest larger integer

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

Below is my code to solve the following problem:

Write a function, `nearest_larger(arr, i)` which takes an array and an
index.  The function should return another index, `j`: this should
satisfy:

(a) `arr[i] < arr[j]`, AND
(b) there is no `j2` closer to `i` than `j` where `arr[i] < arr[j]`.

In case of ties choose the earliest (left-most)
of the two indices. If no number in `arr` is larger than `arr[i]`,
return `nil`.

This was my attempt:

```
def nearest_larger(arr, i)
k = 1
loop do 
    jleft = i - k
    jright = i + k
    if (arr[i] < arr[jleft]) && (jleft >= 0)
        return jleft
    elsif (arr[i] < arr[jright]) && (jright < arr.length)
        return jright
    elsif (jleft < 0) && (jright >= arr.length)
        return nil
    end
    k += 1
end
end
```

This is the actual correct answer

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  diff = 1
  loop do
    left = idx - diff
    right = idx + diff

    if (left >= 0) && (arr[left] > arr[idx])
      return left
    elsif (right < arr.length) && (arr[right] > arr[idx])
      return right
    elsif (left < 0) && (right >= arr.length)
      return nil
    end

    diff += 1
  end
end
```

While my code works well for many of the values I tested when I use certain combinations like this:

```
x = [1,6,9,4,5]
puts nealest_larger(x, 4)
```

I get this error

```
calc.rb:8:in `<': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)
        from calc.rb:8:in `block in nealest_larger'
        from calc.rb:3:in `loop'
        from calc.rb:3:in `nealest_larger'
        from calc.rb:40:in `<main>'
```

Can someone tell me how my code differs from the actual answer, to me it seems like it should behave exactly the same but I must have missed some syntax or overlooked a piece of logic. I need another pair of eyes as I am unable to see the difference, thanks!

Comment: How is `j2` relevant to condition (b)?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version uses array indices before you've checked that they're in-bounds, i.e., on the left-hand side of the `&&`.  The working version checks for in-bounds first, then uses the index if it's legal.  Because Ruby `&&` short circuits, `test && use` approach avoids the problem you ran into with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The 8th line of code in your solution compares the values in the array *before* first checking the bounds of the array.  Notice the correct solution does those comparisons in the reverse order, and the && operator short circuits, avoiding the second (invalid) comparison.